# SQLite 3 Tree List Without CTE

Tags: sqlite, cte

I adapted a SQL statement to work with SQLite 3. But unfortunately Common Table Expressions and WITH clause works only in SQLite 3.6 ahead, but the users of my Open Source application are using SQLite 3.2 and I cannot force them to update the whole Linux system to get the new packages. Is it possible to adapt the code to work without using a CTE and  "With" Clause using only SQL Language?

Here's the code:

```
WITH 
cte AS 
   (SELECT 0 AS level, collectionID, collectionName, parentCollectionID, CAST(collectionID AS VARCHAR(128)) AS Sort
           FROM collections WHERE parentCollectionID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.level + 1, c.collectionID, c.collectionName, c.parentCollectionID, CAST(p.Sort || '/' || CAST(c.collectionID AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(128))
          FROM collections c
          INNER JOIN cte p ON p.collectionID = c.parentCollectionID)
SELECT 
collectionID, 
printf('%*s', level * 4, '') || collectionName AS collectionName, 
Sort,
parentCollectionID 
FROM cte
ORDER BY Sort;
```

Here's the result:

```
collectionID    collectionName            Sort     parentCollectionID
1               Dissertação               1        0
10              Filosofia Reformacional   10       0
11              Dooyeweerd                11       0
14              ZotPad favorites          14       0
15              Diversos                  15       0 
2               Bíblia                    2        0
3               Políticas Públicas        3        0
4               Zotero                    4        0
5               Linux                     5        0   
6               Tese Doutorado            6        0
12                  Pontal Do Paraná      6/12     6
7                   Multimodal            6/7      6
13                     Modalidades        6/7/13   7
8                      Base Histórica     6/7/8    7
9              Artigo Weber               9        0
```

Thank you so much,
Best regards,
Christian

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name I can explain. It's because SQLite 3.8.6 (that implements CTE) is only available to install via PPA for Ubuntu 14.10. In Ubuntu 14.04 there's only SQLite 3.8.2. As the users of my Open Source application are using Ubuntu 14.04 because it is a Long Term Support version I have this problem.

Comment: But SQLite is only a single library, can't you just bundle that with your application? I don't use Linux so I might miss something obvious. But tying a library to an operating system version makes no sense to me (as a Windows user)

Comment: I understand you  a_horse_with_no_name , but in Linux libraries have dependencies. If you alter something you'll affect a lot of stuff.

Comment: Please, a_horse_with_no_name check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell

Comment: If you ask the question at askubuntu.com , they will probably know a way to install the latest version of sqlite3. I've installed and used the latest Postgres in Debian which has similar policy.